# БИОС прерывание INT, подмененное на CALL, не срабатывает

Tags: ассемблер, bios, прерывания, x86

Я хотел сделать call far к адресу таблицы векторов прерываний для 13 прерывания (в моем случае адрес в 0х4С 0000f000) после сохранения флагов на стек, работая из бутлодера. 13ое прерывание не сработало (которое должно писать 200h байтов с адреса 0х0). Это очень странно, так как Вики говорят, что прерывания взаимозаменяемы в реальном режиме с дальними вызовами после сохранения флагов на стек: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_(x86_instruction) . Поэтому это крайне важно, чтобы это срабатывало безукоризненно. На всякий, я попробовал вызов с 4 вариациями адреса (F0 по очереди в каждом байте), безрезультатно.

```
[bits 16]
[org 0x7c00]
xor ax, ax
cli
mov es, ax
mov al, 0x01
mov bx, 0x7c00
mov cx, 0x0004
mov dl, 0x80
xor dh, dh
mov ah, 0x03
pushf
call 0xf000:0x0000
;int 0x13
times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

Этот же вопрос задан англоговорящим пользователям: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53870314/bios-interrupt-replaced-with-far-call-not-working

Comment: Я уже подзабыл ассемблер... ваш вызов - это не вызов ли **кода** по указанному адресу? В то время как там хранится адрес прерывания? Да и потом, сам адрес очень смущает...

Comment: Не совсем. Одно, если делать вызов и в скобках указывать на адрес с адресом. А я уже, допустим, видел адрес, и хочу просто на него перейти.

Comment: Т.е. да, это вызов кода, но этот код и должен выполняться, потому что это место, на которое указывается в адресе прерывания.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Следующее странное поведение БИОСа было обнаружено, что объясняет, почему дальний вызов не срабатывает.

Когда вы выполняете код в этом вопросе просто с INT 13h, с целью записать свою таблицу векторов прерываний с es:bx 0x0:0x0 в сектор на вашем накопителе, вы можете не получить точную реплику своей RAM. У меня были там нулики, аски строки, явно не нормальные адреса. Даже когда я попытался сделать дальний вызов на адрес, который всплыл и казался правильным, это не вызвало выполнение кода прерывания, что иллюстрирует поддельную таблицу векторов, получаемую мной.

Считывая и выводя биты в буфер экрана, не используя прерывания вообще, действительно, кажется, показывает настоящую таблицу прерываний, и уж точно эти данные полностью разнятся с результатом 13h прерывания.

Я думаю, что негативные последствия существования этого явления вам понятны.

Я быстро написал следующий код для ассемблера, чтобы напечатать первые 20 записей таблицы векторов прерываний на экране без использования прерываний вообще:

```
[bits 16]
[org 0x7C00]

xor ax, ax
cli
mov ax, 0xb800
mov es, ax
mov di, 0
mov ax, 0
mov ds, ax
mov si, 0x0     ;начальный адрес ОЗУ, 0 для таблицы
mov cx, 0
mov dl, 20      ;сколько векторов печатать (<25 VGA)
moreints:
mov bh, 4       ; счетчик для байтов каждого вектора 
morebytes:      
mov ah, [ds:si]
mov bl, 8       ;counter for bits of each byte to print
morebits:
shl ah, 1
mov al, 48
jnc zero
mov al, 49
zero:
mov [es:di], al
inc di
inc di
dec bl
jnz morebits
mov al, 32
mov [es:di], al
inc di
inc di
inc si
dec bh
jnz morebytes
add cx, 80*2
mov di, cx
dec dl
jnz moreints
times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

Теперь вы можете найти точные адреса подпрограмм прерываний и дизассембоироавать их в исследовательских целях. Если у вас странные данные, это может указывать на присутствие БИОС руткита, среди всего прочего. Вы даже можете найти разные смысловые смещения и сегменты, такие как F0FA или В0ВА, как Владимир Владимирович Путин.

Подручное напоминание, как читать адреса из таблицы векторов прерываний: допустим, вы получаете 0х12345678 в одной записи для прерывания. Ваш сегмент и смещение будут 0х7856:0х3412.

И используя адрес, полученный таким способом, для дальнего вызова после pushf, вы получите ожидаемое поведение и задействуете код прерывания. Только что проверил, все работает.